# How can I solve react dom warning message?

Tags: reactjs

How to solve this warning message?
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`SocialLogin`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `SocialLogin`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are rendering an element without knowing it is loaded or not.
In socialLogin while navigation this problem occurs.

put the navigation inside useEffect() hope this will solve the problem.